# Symfony2: Multiple Prototypes for an array field

Tags: php, symfony

I have an Entity `Article` which contains:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array") 
 */
private $data;
```

My `data` field can be in different shapes, either `(x1 & x2)` or `(y1, y2 & y3)` .. etc.

I created a `FormType` for each one of them but i'm confused on how i present those prototypes to the `ArticleType` form and the user can be free to choose to insert either X or Y or multiple of those, I know i need a `Collection` for that with `allow_add` option but i need a way to insert multiple `types` in that collection.

My plan is to have X number of buttons, each button has a prototype, once the user click on that button, the prototype will be inserted to the form[data] field.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do so you should create a new form type similar to collection, but allowing several prototypes. see example implementation:
https://github.com/infinite-networks/InfiniteFormBundle/blob/master/Form/Type/PolyCollectionType.php
https://gist.github.com/merk/3058342